# What software to use for online screening of candidates?

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, web-apps, gui

I wanted to conduct online screening of candidates for interview purpose and the type of questions include:

1. Multiple choice questions
2. Coding Questions
3. Fill in the blanks
4. Questions required to be answered in few 2-3 lines

I want to create my own questions. User need to register using email id and take the test.
What are the good recommendations for this? Open to both open source, free and paid software.

I already explored Moodle. But one problem I see is, we need to create a course and then create tests. Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.imocha.io/

- Long standing company used by many companies mostly IT companies
- Have a good customer support

They support access key system where you can send access key to your candidates and they register and take tests on iMocha website.

There is some online services out there to help with these type of process, but in most cases user registering should by handled by yourself as they handle only testing the candidates you provided

Comment: That's four answers.  Please post each one separately so that they may be voted upon and accepted separately.

Comment: @Chenmunka thanks for notifying me, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codingame.com/

The main site is for just code based game, but they also support skill assessment for employers all alike.

- You must handle registration and sending a generated link to the test to send to you candidates
- Supports a collaborative coding interview, where you can assess your candidate in action.
- Very intuitive interface, there is very little learning curve.
- Supports all of your needs